# How do I test the stationarity of data using minitab?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, minitab

I am working on a time series and trying to fit ARIMA to predict future values.However,
I am facing trouble with finding out whether the data is stationary or not.

Comment: Might be a duplicate, see:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129893/time-series-stationarity     http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47302/stationarity-tests-for-time-series          http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52505/what-are-the-assumptions-for-checking-the-stationarity-of-a-time-series

Answer (score 2):

I believe you know how to check whether the data is stationary or not by looking at the ACF & PACF plots.

To do this in Minitab, we use **Stat - Time Series - Autocorrelation** and **Stat - Time Series - Partial Autocorrelation**.

With no data given here I would suggest you to refer this [document](http://www.math.mun.ca/~sneddon/st3540/acfintro.rtf). Hope this helps !